# Need help on mongo aggregation query

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework, spring-data-mongodb

Below is the sample data:

```
[{
        "outdoor": {
            "location": {
                "type": "Point",
                "coordinates": [
                    -92.41151,
                    35.11683
                ]
            }
        },
        "geoHash": "dr72jwgnbbst", "status":"Active","customerId":"8047380094","locationId":"A0"

    },
    {
        "outdoor": {
            "location": {
                "type": "Point",
                "coordinates": [
                    -89.58342,
                    36.859161
                ]
            }
        },
        "geoHash": "dn6qtkr5xk8m", "status":"Pending","customerId":"8047380094","locationId":"A1"
    },
    {
        "outdoor": {

            "location": {
                "type": "Point",
                "coordinates": [
                    -86.038762,
                    36.519016
                ]
            }
        },
        "geoHash": "dn6zf0h6xtcp", "status":"Active","customerId":"8047380094","locationId":"A2"
    },
    {
        "outdoor": {
            "location": {
                "type": "Point",
                "coordinates": [
                    -98.3081936,
                    26.2143207
                ]
            }
        },
        "geoHash": "9udj4unjmp9f", "status":"Pending","customerId":"8047380094","locationId":"A3"
    },
    {
        "outdoor": {
            "location": {
                "type": "Point",
                "coordinates": [
                    -98.5377275,
                    29.4878928
                ]
            }
        },
        "geoHash": "9v1zv8p52t8u", "status":"Pending","customerId":"8047380094","locationId":"A4"
    },
    {
        "outdoor": {
            "location": {
                "type": "Point",
                "coordinates": [
                    -73.7018126,
                    42.641387
                ]
            }
        },
        "geoHash": "dreddfeup69m", "status":"Pending","customerId":"8047380094","locationId":"A5"
    },
    {
        "outdoor": {
            "location": {
                "type": "Point",
                "coordinates": [
                    -111.865295,
                    33.431942
                ]
            }
        },
        "geoHash": "9tbqnqn5jtwq", "status":"Active","customerId":"8047380094","locationId":"A6"
    },
    {
        "outdoor": {
            "location": {
                "type": "Point",
                "coordinates": [
                    -79.810763,
                    34.174603
                ]
            }
        },
        "geoHash": "dnp4rv796rtz", "status":"Active","customerId":"8047380094","locationId":"A7"
    }
]
```

Currently we are running 2 queries:

Query 1 - This query will give the counts by status grouped by geoHash substring.

```
db.locations.aggregate([{"$match": {"customerId": "8047380094"}}, {"$project": {"status": 1, "geoHash": {"$substr": ["$geoHash", 0, 2]}}}, {"$group": {"_id": {"geoHash": "$geoHash", "status": "$status"}, "statusCount": {"$sum": 1}}}],
{
  "allowDiskUse": true
});
```

Output 1:

```
{ "_id" : { "geoHash" : "dr", "status" : "Active" }, "statusCount" : 1 }
{ "_id" : { "geoHash" : "dr", "status" : "Pending" }, "statusCount" : 1 }
{ "_id" : { "geoHash" : "dn", "status" : "Active" }, "statusCount" : 2 }
{ "_id" : { "geoHash" : "dn", "status" : "Pending" }, "statusCount" : 1 }
{ "_id" : { "geoHash" : "9u", "status" : "Pending" }, "statusCount" : 1 }
{ "_id" : { "geoHash" : "9v", "status" : "Pending" }, "statusCount" : 1 }
{ "_id" : { "geoHash" : "9t", "status" : "Active" }, "statusCount" : 1 }
```

Query 2 - We have a query to get the first location coordinates for the geohash group.

```
db.locations.aggregate([{"$match": {"customerId": "8047380094"}}, {"$project": {"geoHash": {"$substr": ["$geoHash", 0, 2]}, "locations": "$outdoor.location.coordinates"}}, {"$group": {"_id": "$geoHash", "locations": {"$push": "$locations"}}}, {"$project": {"_id": 1, "locations": {"$arrayElemAt": ["$locations", 0]}}}],
{
  "allowDiskUse": true
});
```

Output 2:

```
{ "_id" : "dr", "locations" : [ -92.41151, 35.11683 ] }
{ "_id" : "dn", "locations" : [ -89.58342, 36.859161 ] }
{ "_id" : "9u", "locations" : [ -98.3081936, 26.2143207 ] }
{ "_id" : "9v", "locations" : [ -98.5377275, 29.4878928 ] }
{ "_id" : "9t", "locations" : [ -111.865295, 33.431942 ] }
```

Question 1:
Is there any we can combine both queries into 1 and get both the outputs in a single query?

Question 2:
If the total count is 1 (not by status), we need to get the locationId also? How can we achieve this in the same query?
In the above case,
for "9u", we need to return A3
for "9v", we need to return A4
for "9t", we need to return A6

Note: We are using spring boot application with spring mongo.

Comment: Without a sort, the documents may or may not be returned in the same order, what determines which location is "first"?  What is "total count"? The number of documents in the collection, number per user, per hash substring?

Comment: yes, total = no. of douments per customer per hash substring

Comment: @pal.nag does the answer help you?

Answer (score 0):

I didn't go what you try to achieve, because the question doesn't mention it. But for you both question, I can answer

1. You can use `$facet` to use create multiple aggregation pipeline
2. By using the first `$facet` stage, you can use additional stage to get your locationId;

Here is the code

```
{
    $project: {
      firstQuery: 1,
      secondQuery: {
        $map: {
          input: "$secondQuery",
          as: "s",
          in: {
            $mergeObjects: [
              "$$s",
              {
                $arrayElemAt: [
                  {
                    $map: {
                      input: {
                        $filter: {
                          input: "$firstQuery",
                          as: "f",
                          cond: { $eq: ["$$f._id.geoHash", "$$s._id" ] }
                        }
                      },
                      in: { locationId: "$$this.locationId" }
                    }
                  },
                  0
                ]
              }
            ]
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
```

**Working [Mongo playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/e9gGHfibA81)**

Note: Make sure `{ $eq: ["$$f._id.geoHash", "$$s._id" ] }` will give one unique object. Else need another idea. And I feel your posted both queries more like same. So there can be a easy solution. But I answered based on the question you posted